# PHP - GetImageSize()

Tags: php, image, file, upload, getimagesize

I'm trying to use the `getimagesize()` function on an image uploading script.
Sometimes, on certain images, I get an error.
So I tried to investigate.

I used an image which seems to work, edited it with paint.exe, and saved it as a new jpg image.

When I look at the `$_FILES[]`, I get this :

Original :

```
$_FILES : array(2) {
  ["thumb_a_uploader"]=> array(5) {
    ["name"]=> string(8) "1212.jpg"
    ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phprZ2H8G"
    ["error"]=> int(0)
    ["size"]=> int(90281)
  }
```

Edited :

```
$_FILES : array(2) {
  ["thumb_a_uploader"]=> array(5) {
    ["name"]=> string(16) "1212 - Copy.jpg"
    ["type"]=> string(0) ""
    ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) ""
    ["error"]=> int(2)
    ["size"]=> int(0)
  }
```

And for the edited one, the imagetype was wiped.
I have the same problem with a picture taken with a smartphone.

Any ideas ?

Comment: you are getting `error => 2` this error is `UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE Value: 2; The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pay **attention** to `["error"]`.

```
["error"]=>
int(2)
```

---

```
 UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE
```

> Value: `2`; The uploaded file exceeds the `MAX_FILE_SIZE` directive that
>   was specified in the HTML form.

Learn more about [php file-upload.errors](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Comment: on my phpinfo() I have this -> post_max_size 64M

And I tried :
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000000000" />

It dosn't work :(